# Re render the main component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, render

The reason for my question is how to reload the data of the main component, Parent component, from a child component.

So for example the following is the main component

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [isReg, setIsReg] = useState(false);
  const [cliente, setCliente] = useState(true);
  
  const [renderAgain, setRenderAgain] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {

    getItem("isRegistered").then(res => {
      if (res!=null){
        setIsReg(true);
        getItem("clientType").then(res => {
          if (res=="1"){
            setCliente(true)
          }else{
            setCliente(false)
          }
        })
      }
      else{
        setIsReg(false);
      }
    });

}, [renderAgain]);

return(
<IonApp>
<IonReactRouter>
<IonSplitPane contentId="main" when="(min-width: 4096px)">
      <Menu renderAgain={renderAgain} setRenderAgain={setRenderAgain} />
  <IonRouterOutlet id="main">

    <Route path="/" render={() => isReg ?   ( cliente ?  <HomeCliente setRenderAgain={setRenderAgain}/> : <HomeProveedor setRenderAgain={setRenderAgain}/> ) : <Inicio /> } />
    <Route path="/home" render={() =>  isReg ? (cliente ?  <HomeCliente setRenderAgain={setRenderAgain}/> : <HomeProveedor setRenderAgain={setRenderAgain}/> ): <Inicio /> } ></Route>
    <Route path="/registro" render={() => isReg ?   ( cliente ?  <HomeCliente setRenderAgain={setRenderAgain}/> : <HomeProveedor setRenderAgain={setRenderAgain}/> ) : <Registro /> } />

    <Route path="/ingresar" render={() => isReg ?   ( cliente ?  <HomeCliente setRenderAgain={setRenderAgain}/> : <HomeProveedor setRenderAgain={setRenderAgain}/> ) :<Ingresar setRenderAgain={setRenderAgain} />} /> 
  
    <Route path="/Completarinfo" render={() => <Completarinfo setRenderAgain={setRenderAgain} renderAgain={renderAgain} />}  />
    <Route path="/CompletarRubros" component={CompletarRubros} exact={true}  

  </IonRouterOutlet>
  </IonSplitPane>
</IonReactRouter>
</IonApp>

);
};
```

As you can see in the main component's useEffect, the data saved on the device is searched. To verify if you are registered and what type of client it is.

In this way, if it is not registered, the Inicio component is rendered. Where it gives you the option to enter or register. Now, once it is started or registered, you have to go to / home, but it is necessary again to see in the useEffect of the main component if it is logged in, and for that I use the renderAgain hook, saying that you have to re-execute the useEffect from App.

```
const IngresarDatos = (props:{ setRenderAgain:any, setShowLoading:any, setShowAlertUsuarioContraseñaIncorrectos:any,  setShowAlertServerConnection:any, setShowAlertCompletarInfo:any, setShowAlertContraseñaCambiada:any, setShowAlertContraseñaNoIguales:any, setShowAlertBadEmail:any, setShowAlertBadCode:any}) => {
  
    const axios = require('axios');
    const [home, setHome]=useState(false)
  
    const [restaurar, setRestaurar]=useState(0)

    const password = useRef(0)
    const email=useRef("")

    if(home){
      
      props.setRenderAgain(true)
      return(<Redirect push={true} to="/home" />);
     
    }
  
    const validarRestauracion = () => {
      setRestaurar(3)
    }

    const ingresar = () => {
      if((email.current!= null && email.current!= undefined && email.current!="")&& (password.current!=null && password.current!= undefined )){
  
        props.setShowLoading(true)
  
        axios.get(url+"ingresar/"+email.current+"/"+password.current, {timeout: 7000})
        .then((res: { data: any; }) => {
          const resquest = res.data;
          console.log(res.data)
          if(resquest=="usuario y contraseña no válidos"){
            props.setShowLoading(false)
            props.setShowAlertUsuarioContraseñaIncorrectos(true)
  
          }
          else if(resquest[0].picture ==""){
            setItem("isRegistered", resquest[0].user).then(() =>{
                setItem("clientType", resquest[0].clientType).then(() =>{
                  setItem("personalInfoCompleted",false).then(() =>{
                    props.setShowLoading(false)
                    setHome(true)
                  })
                })
              
            });
            
  
          }
          else{
            setItem("isRegistered", email.current).then(() =>{
             
              setItem("fotoPersonal", resquest[0].picture).then(() =>{
                setItem("clientType", resquest[0].clientType).then(() =>{
                  setItem("personalInfoCompleted",true).then(() =>{
                    props.setShowLoading(false)
                    setHome(true)
                  })
                })
              })
            });
          }
        }).catch((err: any) => {
          // what now?
         props.setShowLoading(false)
          props.setShowAlertServerConnection(true)
      })
      }else{
        props.setShowAlertCompletarInfo(true)
      }  
  
    }
```

When the data is verified, home is equal to true and therefore the following is executed:

```
    if(home){   
      props.setRenderAgain(true)
      return(<Redirect push={true} to="/home" />);
    }
```

It is redirected to home, the problem is that if I don't change renderAgain, the home page won't reload unless I refresh the browser.Am I doing things right? How is it possible to reload the main component correctly so that it checks which url it should go to?

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the setState directly to props add a function in the main component first and then pass it to props.
in the main component :

```
// ...code
const handleRenderAgain = (render: boolean) => setRenderAgain(render);
// ...code
<Menu renderAgain={renderAgain} setRenderAgain={handleRenderAgain} />
// ...rest of the code
```